# Rounded corners on tables - Auto-generated documents using MS word template?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, templates

Is it possible to make tables in word have rounded corners?

OR

If using shape, with rounded corners, as wrapper for table/text, is it possible to make that shape dynamically change size based on content.

This is to make a template that will be generated automatically based on database content. So no human will be involved in creating the file, only database content.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to make tables in word have round corners, but you can refer to this link as a workaround:

[Word Table Borders: are rounded corners possible?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/word-table-borders-are-rounded-corners-possible/7c9bfcf6-3820-4ed3-bc70-0b7e2030a5a1?db=5&auth=1)

But I don't think it is possible to make that shape dynamically change size based on content.